# wordpress not save spaces between line

Tags: php, wordpress

When I create post wordpress not save spaces between lines:

Code:

```
    <div class="postas">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    <!-- End Main Content -->
    </div>
```

Wordpress only add `&nbsp;` symbol if I press double-click Enter button, but if I second time edit this post `&nbsp;` symbols disapear

Comment: You don't need to wrap `<?php the_content(); ?>` with `<p></p>`.  I'm not sure I understand your question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress does some auto-formatting on your posts.  The auto-formatting occurs when you save your post, or if you swtich between the HTML and Visual modes in the content editor.

If you are trying to do something that gets erased by this formatting, you may want to try disabling the auto-formatting Wordpress includes.

You can do this by installing this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ps-disable-auto-formatting/

After installing the plugin, you can choose to enable/disable formatting in your Dashboard Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying between every post?? If yes you should use css, and is better if you add another div only for

so with css you can use margin to set margins